# How to access FantasyData API from R?

Tags: r, httr

I am attempting to grab data from a sports API ([documentation](https://developer.fantasydata.com/docs/services/57a0190935491a1858749954/operations/57a0190a35491a0ef079a14a)) that I recently signed up for.  I have the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key but am unsure how to pass it to the GET request

My question is, how do I authenticate myself with these credentials / keys inside of R. If I run the following:

```
library(httr)
this_json <- GET("https://api.fantasydata.net/v3/nfl/scores/JSON/ScoresByWeek/2015REG/1")
```

It returns a 401 status, which wikipedia says is an unauthorized status. Are there functions in the httr library that I can use to authenicate myself?

Comment: There is no standard for API authentication. You will need to read the documentation for the specific API you are interested in using to see what they require. Alternatively contact the developers of that API.

Comment: okay good to know, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation you provided for the Fantasy Data API](https://developer.fantasydata.com/docs/services/57a0190935491a1858749954/operations/57a0190a35491a0ef079a14a), you are required to pass the "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" (whatever that is) as a header to your HTTP requestion. You can do this with `httr` using `add_headers()`

```
this_json <- GET("https://api.<myapiprovider>.net/linktofeeds/JSON/etc", 
   add_headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"= "<your-key-here>"))
```